# Getting DacServices error on one machine, not on another

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dac, bacpac

We've got a process that includes creating a database on an SQL Server 11 and 10 database servers. We're using a dacpac to import this data in C# via DacServices. This is the code being used:

```
var dac = new DacServices(masterConnString);
using (var bacPac = BacPackage.Load(templatePath))
{
    dac.ImportBacpac(bacPac, dealer.VSID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

When we run this for initial testing from our local machines, it works as expected. However, when I toss this up on a server (it runs as part of a WCF service). I get the following error:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices' threw
>   an exception.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IWcfService.Method(String
>   string, Int32 integer)    at
>   WcfServiceClient.Method(String string, Int32 integer)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds to me just from reading your issue that there is a `Dll assembly` issue how is that particular assembly referenced locally.. is it marked `CopyLocal = true` also could this be a `GAC` check all your references and make sure they are the same on the target machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this figured out. The offending DLL was Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom. Once I referenced that, everything worked as expected. Took a lot of digging to get to that spot though.